# Latex mirror margins

Tags: spacing

I need to have my document binded after being being printed, and so I need a 3.75 margin on every page on the side that will be binded. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: have a look at the `geometry` package; in particular, you'll want to look at `bindingoffset`. also make sure that you are loading `twoside` into your `documentclass` (assuming it needs it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bindingoffset from geometry allows you to do this, here is an extreme example, change to suit. Margin of 1 inch all round, and an extra 1 inch for binding.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,bindingoffset=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```